# Passing char* by value

Tags: c++, parameter-passing

Will the following code work? -

```
void doSomething(char* in)
{
    strcpy(in,"mytext");
}
```

Here's how the function is being called:

```
doSomething(testIn);
OtherFn(testIn);
```

The `char* in` is used in other places in the code... and we are passing it by value to the function `doSomething`. I understand when we pass by value, a copy of the string stored in `char*` is copied within the function. So, when we do a `strcpy`, will it copy to the local copy or to the `char* in` that was passed in as an argument?

My understanding is we need to do: `doSomething(char* &in)`.  Is that right?

Comment: testIn is a char * right?

Comment: BTW: no, "a copy of the string stored in `char*` is *not* copied within the function." Only the pointer value is copied, not the string pointed _to_.

Comment: You're not showing the important code, which is how `testIn` is initialised: it needs to be something like `char testIn[100];` (or dynamically with `new[]`), not just `char* testIn;` or `char* testIn = 0;` which don't set `testIn` to point to actual memory for the character content you attempt to copy into it in `doSomething()`.

Answer (score 3):

When you want to modify just the contents of what the pointer points to, use:

```
doSomething(char* in)
```

So, yes,

```
void doSomething(char* in)
{
   strcpy(in,"mytext");
}
```

will work just fine as long as `in` points to enough memory to hold `"mytest"` and a terminating null character.

There are times when you want to modify where the pointer points to, for example, by allocating new memory. Then, you need to pass a reference to a pointer.

```
void doSomething(char*& in)
{
   in = new char[200];
   strcpy(in,"mytext");
}
```

and use it as:

```
char* s = NULL;
doSomething(s);
// Now s points to memory that was allocated in doSomething.

// Use s


// make sure to deallocate the memory.
delete [] s;
```

Comment: by value of pointer, you mean the address? Here, I need to modify the contents of the pointer.

Comment: @techieChamp, that's what I mean.

Comment: @juanchopanza, I read the answer after your comment and what you said made sense. It's updated now.